# Changing the order of my code result in error ?

Tags: ruby

```
     def stock_picker prices
        min_day , max_day , profit = 0 , 0 , 0
        i = 1
        while i < prices.length    
            (0...i).each do |day|
              if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
                  min_day , max_day , profit = day , i , prices[i] - prices[day]
              end
                #i += 1
            end
            i += 1
        end

            return "[#{min_day}, #{max_day}]"
      end

        prices = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]

        puts stock_picker prices
```

My objective is to implement a method #stock_picker that takes in an array of stock prices, one for each hypothetical day. It should return a pair of days representing the best day to buy and the best day to sell. Days start at 0.

My question is why is it that this code wouldn't work if I remove line 11 and wrote it on line 9 instead. Which will then result in the error as follows :

```
**PS C:\Users\dlim\mystuff> ruby stockpicker.rb
stockpicker.rb:8:in `block in stock_picker': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from stockpicker.rb:7:in `each'
        from stockpicker.rb:7:in `stock_picker'
        from stockpicker.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Where is this occurring?**

Your error

> ```
> stockpicker.rb:8:in `block in stock_picker': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>    from stockpicker.rb:7:in `each'
>    from stockpicker.rb:7:in `stock_picker'
>    from stockpicker.rb:29:in `<main>'
> ```

Is occurring on 8th line

```
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
```

When it tries to access `prices[i]` when `i = 9` and the `prices` returns `nil`,
which does not respond to the minus `-` operator.

**Why is this occurring?**

You are a loop within a loop

```
(0...i).each do |day|
  if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
      min_day , max_day , profit = day , i , prices[i] - prices[day]
  end
  #i += 1
end
```

Increasing the `i` index counter variable here does not really make sense, since
the `day` is already iterating over the values in the Range `(0...i)` and
increasing `i` inside this loop means its comparing every value in the `prices`
array **once** against the next `day` value in the `prices` inner array, which
will only include the first three values of the `prices` (meaning the values at
the end of the `prices` array, like `1` and `10` will never be compared against
one another); e.g.

```
i = 1
prices = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]

# iteration 0
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#          3 - 17 > 0 # => false


# iteration 1
i += 1 # => 2
day # => 0

if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#          6 - 17 > 0 # => false

i += 1 # => 3
day # => 1


# iteration 2
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#          9 - 3 > 0 # => true
min_day, max_day, profit = 1, 3, 6

i += 1 # => 4
day # => 0


# iteration 3
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#          15 - 17 > 0 # => false

i += 1 # => 5
day # => 1


# iteration 4
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#          8 - 3 > 0 # => true

min_day, max_day, profit = 1, 5, 5
i += 1 # => 6
day # => 2


# iteration 5
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#          6 - 6 > 0 # => false

i += 1 # => 7
day # => 3


# iteration 6
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#          1 - 9 > 0 # => false

i += 1 # => 8
day # => 0


# iteration 7
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#         10 - 17 > 0 # => false

i += 1 # => 9
day # => 1


# iteration 8
if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
#        nil - 3 > 0 # => NoMethodError
```

At the 8th iteration, the outer loop has caused an out of bounds error when
accessing the prices array with `prices[i]`, but is still iterating within the
second loop with the Range of `(0...7)` that was set after the 5th iteration, so
it is not reaching your while loop's escape clause/expression
`while i < prices.length`.

**Possible solution:**

You could keep your working solution or you could simplify your code by using
another Range as the outer loop

```
(1...prices.length).each do |i|
  # ...
end
```

Instead of increasing an index counter variable within the while loop

```
i = 1
while i < prices.length
  # ...
  i +=1
end
```

Which would look like this

```
def stock_picker prices
  min_day , max_day , profit = 0 , 0 , 0
  (1...prices.length).each do |i|
    (0...i).each do |day|
      if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
        min_day , max_day , profit = day , i , prices[i] - prices[day]
      end
    end
  end

  return "[#{min_day}, #{max_day}]"
end

prices = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]

puts stock_picker prices
```

And it will iterate over the following pairs of days, as per your requirements

```
[i, day]
# => [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0],
#    [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1],
#    [3, 2], [4, 2], [5, 2], [6, 2], [7, 2], [8, 2],
#    [4, 3], [5, 3], [6, 3], [7, 3], [8, 3],
#    [5, 4], [6, 4], [7, 4], [8, 4],
#    [6, 5], [7, 5], [8, 5],
#    [7, 6], [8, 6],
#    [8, 7]
```

**UPDATE:**

You could also simplify it again with the [Ruby Array `combination` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination)

```
(0...prices.length).to_a.combination(2)
```

To generate the same unique and non-duplicate pairs of days as iterating over the Ranges implied, which would look like this

```
def stock_picker prices
  min_day , max_day , profit = 0 , 0 , 0
  (0...prices.length).to_a.combination(2).each do |day, i|
    if prices[i] - prices[day] > profit
      min_day , max_day , profit = day , i , prices[i] - prices[day]
    end
  end

  return "[#{min_day}, #{max_day}]"
end

prices = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]

puts stock_picker prices
```

*`|day, i|` will access the first and second variables in the array of day index pairs within array of combinations, whilst reusing the existing variable names you have used.*

Comment: Hi in the iteration example, how did you count the number of days?  Shouldn't the days just +1 each time it iterates as per the range (0...1). From what i understand is that at iteration 0 , day should be 0  , at iteration 1 , day should be 1 , iteration 2 day should be 2 and so forth. I think I am misunderstanding some parts there.

Comment: Rerunning your original code I get the following pairs of `[i, day]` before it hits `nil`: `[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 1], [4, 0], [5, 1], [6, 2], [7, 3], [8, 0], [9, 1]`.

The reason it is `0` twice for iteration 0 and iteration 1, is because of the inclusive vs exclusive Range used; e.g. `(0..1).to_a # => [0, 1]` vs `(0...1).to_a # => [0]`. So the Range `(0...1)` will run once, which is iteration 0, and twice for Range `(0...2)`, which is iteration 1 & 2.

> Ranges constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically trying to rewrite [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) and [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) :

```
prices = [17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10]
days = (0...prices.size).to_a
p days.combination(2).max_by { |day1, day2| prices[day2] - prices[day1] }
# => [1,4]
```

If you want both the days and the corresponding prices :

```
[17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10].each.with_index.to_a.
                       combination(2).max_by{|(buy, day1), (sell, day2)|
                         sell-buy
                       }
# => [[3, 1], [15, 4]]
```